# Best way to implement a table with rows that can scroll horizontally?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on a Netflix-styled UI, a table with rows that can scroll horizontally.

A few years ago I coded this up as collection views inside a table view.

Now I am wondering whether I can do this with a single collection view, with a custom layout. The advantage of the new approach is that animations that go from one row to another row can be done with layout transitions, something the collection view supports natively.

Can this be done? I don't think it's possible, but I am curious what you think.

Comment: What about transform/rotate your TableView and your Cells by 90°?

Comment: I don't know what looks like Netflix UI, but it certainly could be done with an `UICollectionView`. In the custom Layout, you can set that the scroll is horizontal.

Comment: @Larme - then you lose the ability to scroll vertically.

Comment: @derdida - you are misunderstanding the question. You are suggesting an old technique to scroll a table horizontally. That is not necessary anymore, since collection views can scroll horizontally.

Comment: @EvilNodoer: I thought you wanted to "disable" the vertical scrolling, my bad. I misunderstood, I don't know how Netflix UI looks like.

Comment: You should edit your question to include a description of the UI you want for those who don't have the Netflix app.